# Electric Box Fan was spinning on its own

Tags: switch, fans

I just had a strange experience. I woke up and I saw the blades of my electric floor box fan spinning very rhythmically. The air condition had just turned off, but the fan was still spinning. It was plugged into the wall, but the power was off. What the heck is this? Is there a reason this happened?

Answer (score 1):

Box fan blade will rotate whilst its motor is turned off if an air current is impinging on the blade surfaces.

Comment: To rephrase this, a windmill is really just a fan that you put in the wind. If you blow air at the fan, it will probably spin. Also, the fan has momentum. It'll keep spinning for a while after you turn it off.